# philosophy of 1st law of thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

Why is there heat emission/absorption when there's work done, at fixed internal energy ? This is a result of the 1st law, but I'm contemplating on the philosophical basis. Why does there have to be heat involved accompanying work done, when  internal energy is not changed? How do heat and work play together?

As an example, when pressing a solid hard keeping it at  the same temperature, the solid doesn't deform or move or change its temperature in the 1st place. As per the 1st law, the solid has to emit heat. But why does the pressing bring about  heat?

Comment: The question was pretty clear indeed. However I edited to make it more clear. I think I have kept the original meaning.

Comment: In your example, real solids do deform (elastically and, if too much, plastically) when pressed on.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not philosophical at all. It a is quite technical indeed.
It is true that the first principle says that a transformation at fixed internal energy implies that if work is done on the system, then heat should be released to the environment.

However your example of pressing a solid at fixed temperature is not a good example of a fixed energy transformation.

The reason is that if temperature is fixed and a pressure is applied, the volume has to change in order some work is done on the system. And indeed isothermal compressibility of a solid, although small is a finite number. 
However, internal energy of a solid is not independent on the volume (deformation).

A relevant example would be an ideal gas kept at constant temperature. In that case, since $U$ depends only on $T$, the isothermal transformation is at constant $U$.

However in such a case it is not misterious that the constraint of fixed temperature  (energy) implies a release of heat: an adiabatic compression would increase energy and temperature of the system. The condition of constant temperature is obtained by establishing a thermal contact between the system and a thermal reservoir, i.e. a big system at constant temperature. So, as soon the compression starts, the ideal gas would get warmer but thermal contact implies some heat release from the system to the reservoir.

Comment: i thought of putting ur example as opposed to mine. but if u put a heat reservoir to hold the temperature, there's heat coming out from the object when pressed. then the heat will go to the reservoir unnoticed.

Comment: a good point that internal energy may depend on the volume as well, as seen in solids and fluids. then let's assume it's a gas

Comment: Why the heat should go unnoticed? One can measure it!

Comment: but the heat gets merged with the heat reservoir together

Comment: Doesn't matter. Since energy is a function of state, the amount of heat released to tthe thermostat is exactly the same released by the same gas put in a calorimeter, provided that initial and final volume and temperature are the same.

Comment: anyway ur answer seems not to answer my question

Comment: From my answer you can get the following chain of steps: compression work -> local increase of temperature in the sample -> temporary difference of temperature between sample and environment in a situation where thermal conduction is allowed -> heat emission to re-establish thermal equilibrium with the constraint of constant temperature. What is not clear in such a sequence ? why do you think it does not answer your question?

Comment: ok. why: compression work -> local increase of temperature in the sample?

Comment: You can always consider a transformation where you do some positive work on the system at fixed energy as obtained by a sequence of steps of adiabatic compression work (which increases the energy of the system) followed by  exchange of heat required to bring back the energy of your system to its original value.

Comment: right. but i asked this question, assuming 1st law of thermodynamics wasn't established yet

Comment: That was absolutely not clear from your question. Moreover, I do not understand how you hope that an explanation on a thermodynamic problem could be given without using the basic laws of thermodynamics. The contradiction of trying to explain why there is heat emission/adsorption at fixed internal energy without the first  principle should be evident when realizing that the existence of something called internal energy is the main conceptual content of the 1st principle.